# What component work earlier in flow? RecordFilterStrategy or ConsumerInterceptor?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have kafka consumer in my spring-boot application. And I need to filter consumed messages. On filtered messages I wan't to do some action's and do not provide to consumer, on the other side I need to continue processing on non filtered messages through my app flow. Can I combine this to approaches like RecordFilterStrategy and ConsumerInterceptor for that peuposes or I can use only something one ? And what the best way for filtering and do some action's on messages in kafka?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#filtering-messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use neither and put conditional statements directly in the Listener method.

But interceptor would run before Spring gets hold of the record.

You could also use Kafka Streams filter/branch operators to optionally process/drop records

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but my kafka message have very complicated structure and condition statements will be very large and non understandable, that's why I don't want to use this approach

Comment: The condition is going to be the same size, no matter what approach you use because one record is going to have the same structure... Any approach you use only acts on one record at a time

Comment: `ConsumerInterceptor` gets the entire `ConsumerRecords` with all records from the poll - so you'd have to build a new one with the filtered list of records; the `RecordFilterStrategy` gets one records at-a-time, so it's probably easier to use for this use case.